# SIGUSR1 is getting ignored when starting binary from system() command

Tags: linux, command-line, signal

I try to use SIGUSR1 with timer. It works fine when starting binary from command line. But if i start same binary from system() command from other application then SIGUSR1 is getting ignored.

**I don't want to ignore SIGUSR1 signal**. How to resolve this issue with signal() or sigaction() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the environment (including blocked or disabled signals) are inherited from the parent process.

If you are talking about a binary executable you control, then you can code it to (re)enable any and all signals.

If you do not, then perhaps you can write a wrapper program that you run instead that will enable the appropriate signals and start the executable.

Comment: How to (re)enable SIGUSR1 signal from application.